# Mysql query tuning (large data set) and explain plan

Tags: mysql, optimization, normalization, explain

I am using mysql5.1, i have table which has about 15 lakh (1.5 million) records.This table has records for  different entities i.e  child records for all master entities.

There are 8 columns in this table , out of which 6 columns are clubbed to make a primary key.
These columns could be individual foreign keys but due to performance we have made this change.

Even a simple select statement with two conditions is taking 6-8 seconds.Below is the explain plan for the same.

Query

```
explain extended 
 select distinct location_code, Max(trial_number) as replication
   from status_trait  t  
  where t.status_id='N02'
    and t.trial_data='orange'
  group by location_code
```

The results of EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
 1  SIMPLE  t   index       FK_HYBRID_EXP_TRAIT_DTL_2   5       1481572 100.00  Using where; Using index
```

I have these questions:

1. How to handle tables with large data
2. Is indexing fine for this table

Comment: [lac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) is a unit of measurement many of us are not familiar with.

Comment: 1.5 million records doesn't seem that much. If you have one index over 6 keys that doesn't help filter the table by 2 of those keys. Try adding individual indexes for each of the columns used for filtering (might occupy a lot of space for nothing if they are not used) or try adding indexes for each group of columns used for filtering.

Comment: That did make a difference but since still my execution time is 3.6 sec **can i reduce more** , now i have created two index one with columns i have used for the above query and other includes some more columns .

Comment: What indexes have you created on this table?

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Two things might help you here.

First, `SELECT DISTINCT` is pointless in an aggregating query. Just use `SELECT`.

Second, you didn't disclose the indexes you have created. However, to satisfy this query efficiently, the following compound covering index will probably help a great deal.

```
(status_id, trial_data, location_code, trial_number)
```

Why is this the right index? Because MySQL indexes are organized as BTREE. This organization allows the server to random-access the index to find particular values. In your case you want particular values of `status_id` and `trial_data`. Once the server has random-accessed the index, it can then scan sequentially.  In this case you hope to scan for various values of `location_code`. The server knows it will find those different values already in order. Finally, the server needs to pluck out values of `trial_number` to use in your `MAX()` function.  Lo and behold, there they are in the index ready for the plucking.

(If you're doing a lot of aggregation and querying of large tables, it makes sense for you to learn how compound and covering indexes work.)

There's a cost to adding an index: when you `INSERT` or `UPDATE` rows, you have to update your index as well. But this kind of index will greatly accelerate your retrieval.

Comment: This made a huge difference i was able to see results in .03 secs. But how much it is going to  cost on my insert and update ?

Comment: Here's the thing: you need the correct indexes on your table to satisfy your common queries efficiently. But you don't need other indexes. From your question it sounds like you've been hacking away at your primary key (which itself is a unique index) to try to boost efficiency. But I wonder whether you've achieved any performance boost. May I suggest you start a question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that presents the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable` and also shows  few of your more common queries? Link to the question here.

Comment: Posted http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47468/sql-indexing-and-performance

Comment: YOu moved thread to dba.stackexchange.com where i cannot comment so i am commenting here as per your comment that for 4th index i can use (experiment_id,trait_name,hybrid_number) what if i have query which uses hybrid_number and trait_name and experiment_id ?